# Opening Multiple Files from any directory in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

**How can I select multiple files from multiple directories? in Tkinter**

I want to note the address of the files which are in different directories
I have tried using *askopenfilenames() file dialog and askopenfilename(...,multiple=True)* but they haven't allowed me to select multiple files from different directories.

Is there any other file dialog that can do. Sorry if this a repeated Question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code might help you

```
import tkinter,tkinter.filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox

root = tkinter.Tk()
def main():
        files = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilenames(parent=root,title='Choose files')
        msgbox = tkinter.messagebox.askquestion ('Add files','add extra files',icon = 'warning')
        return list(files), msgbox

files, msgbox = main()

all_files = files

while msgbox =='yes':
    files_2, msgbox = main()
    for i in files_2:
        files.append(i)
    
root.destroy()
```

*all_files* contains all the directories selected

Comment: I was thinking about opening multiple askopenfilenames but I was wondering if there is a way with only one. But thanks! guess I will go with this method.